# More then 8mb file is not upload in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am try to uploading file on WordPress server.after 8 mb uploading file is break.There are three ways to increase the size of the uploading file.

1. PHP.ini (Changing the settings of PHP.ini file)
2. htaccess (Also change the settings in htaccess file but still of no use)
3. changing settings in wp-admin file.

all are not working.

Is it any other way to increase the size of the  uploading file.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: What type of server are you using and what type of cpanel are you using?  This can vary what file you need to edit.  Personally dealing with zPanel there are special locations for changing these settings and every installation is different which is the reason I ask.  Based on that information, editing the proper PHP.ini file and restarting the http service that is running your PHP it would vary on what file you need to edit.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you are uploading file ie. On which site.
What is your connection bandwidth.

How much uploading your `WordPress service provider` supporting.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the maximum filesize setting, try to look and configure `max_execution_time` and `post_max_size` in the php.ini if necessary. Then,restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure this two things in php.ini upload_max_filesize and post_max_size then restart your webserver

Comment: Thnx for reply ,but i m already try this,but not workingstill

Comment: have you change the max_input_time also?

Answer (score -1):

Your script can have a limited set of time to be executed.

Try set the request timeout inside the php script with set_time_limit() (for a test on time limit, not for an upload)

Often, when the limit is represented by the size of file, you should have a message warning before the upload starts. In this case the server is letting you upload, so in most cases it's not a size problem.

Take into account also that some providers are imposing execution time from web server setup so you have to check this too. If I were you I'll try to execute a script that does nothing (wait) for some minutes, and see if that the time the request goes in timeout is the same for uploading a file.

Comment: The timelimit only starts after the http request, and with it the upload, is complete.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I corrected the answer, set_time_limit can only be used to test if it's the web server that redirects on time out.